# How do I get my code to pick from a food place random generated number?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, random

When I press my button I want it to Randomly select food place from one of the 7 Asian places. When my random number comes out as: 2 I get print out that says

> "Today you will eat at null".

How do I get it to print out the name of the restaurant and link it to a new java page to display it's info?

This is where I declared my array:

```
 private void createResArray() {
    Restaurant chacha = new Restaurant("Cha Cha", FoodCategory.Asian);
    Restaurant sammy = new Restaurant("Sammy Chom's K-Town", FoodCategory.Asian);
    Restaurant sushianddinsum = new Restaurant("Sushi & Dinsum", FoodCategory.Asian);
    Restaurant masterwok = new Restaurant("Master Wok", FoodCategory.Asian);
    Restaurant chinastar = new Restaurant("China Star", FoodCategory.Asian);
    Restaurant phohasaigon = new Restaurant("Pho Ha Saigon", FoodCategory.Asian);


    Restaurant taiAli = new Restaurant("Tai’s Ali's Middle East Food", FoodCategory.Middle_Eastern);
    Restaurant aliMiddle = new Restaurant("Ali's Middle East Food", FoodCategory.Middle_Eastern);
    Restaurant nycHalal = new Restaurant("NYC Halal", FoodCategory.Middle_Eastern);

    resArray = new SparseArray<Restaurant>();

    resArray.append(0, chacha);
    resArray.append(1, sammy);
    resArray.append(2, sushianddinsum);
    resArray.append(3, masterwok);
    resArray.append(4, chinastar);
    resArray.append(5, phohasaigon);


    resArray.append(6, taiAli);
    resArray.append(7, aliMiddle);
    resArray.append(8, nycHalal);
    resCount = 9;
```

This is my random number gen:

```
 private void pickRestaurant(int checkedRadioButtonId) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int randomNumber = -1;

    switch (checkedRadioButtonId) {
        case R.id.Asian:
            randomNumber = r.nextInt(7)+1 ;
            break;
        case R.id.middle_eastern:
            randomNumber = r.nextInt() ;
            break;
```

}

```
    String randomRestaurantName = resArray.get(randomNumber).getName();
    Toast toast = null;
    if (randomNumber < 0) {
        toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Select from one of the following:",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } else {
        toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Today you will eat at "
                + randomRestaurantName , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

}

Resturant.java

```
public class Restaurant {
private String name;
FoodCategory foodCategory;
public String getName;

public Restaurant(String name, FoodCategory priceRange) {
    this.name = name;
    this.foodCategory = priceRange;
}

public String getName()
{
    return getName;
}

protected FoodCategory getFoodCategory()
{
    return foodCategory;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually trying to print the whole Restaurant object. You only want to print the name. Don't know how your Restaurant class looks like, but if it would be something like:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    String name;
    FoodCategory category;

    public Restaurant(String name, FoodCategory category)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
String randomRestaurantName = resArray.get(randomNumber).getName();
```

Comment: I made that line change, but now I get "null" instead of Resturant@77ad49d

Comment: Can you post your class structure?

Comment: You have a property getName; and a method getName(). Delete the property and keep only the method getName() and use that one. As well, the method getName() should return name.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the `toString()` method in your `Restaurant` class to make it return something a bit more sensible.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend overriding toString for an output needed in a single place.  Instead he should have a function that returns the name as a String, like getName()

Comment: Thank you for the response :) I just fixed it using a different method